# Why there is no mpfr_sub_sj (while there is mpfr_set_sj_2exp)?

Tags: mpfr

A simple question: why there is no `mpfr_sub_sj` (while there is `mpfr_set_sj_2exp`)?

More details: for `mpfr_set_xx_2exp` there are `sj` and `uj` variants:

```
$ grep -P 'int mpfr_set_.*_2exp' mpfr.h
__MPFR_DECLSPEC int mpfr_set_z_2exp (mpfr_ptr, mpz_srcptr, mpfr_exp_t,
__MPFR_DECLSPEC int mpfr_set_si_2exp (mpfr_ptr, long, mpfr_exp_t, mpfr_rnd_t);
__MPFR_DECLSPEC int mpfr_set_ui_2exp (mpfr_ptr, unsigned long, mpfr_exp_t,
__MPFR_DECLSPEC int mpfr_set_sj_2exp (mpfr_ptr, intmax_t, intmax_t,
__MPFR_DECLSPEC int mpfr_set_uj_2exp (mpfr_ptr, uintmax_t, intmax_t,
```

However, for `mpfr_sub_xx` there are no `sj` and `uj` variants:

```
$ grep -P 'mpfr_sub_' mpfr.h
__MPFR_DECLSPEC int mpfr_sub_q (mpfr_ptr, mpfr_srcptr, mpq_srcptr, mpfr_rnd_t);
__MPFR_DECLSPEC int mpfr_sub_ui (mpfr_ptr, mpfr_srcptr, unsigned long,
__MPFR_DECLSPEC int mpfr_sub_si (mpfr_ptr, mpfr_srcptr, long, mpfr_rnd_t);
__MPFR_DECLSPEC int mpfr_sub_d (mpfr_ptr, mpfr_srcptr, double, mpfr_rnd_t);
__MPFR_DECLSPEC int mpfr_sub_z (mpfr_ptr, mpfr_srcptr, mpz_srcptr, mpfr_rnd_t);
```

Why? Will it be useful to have `sj` and `uj` variants for `mpfr_sub_xx` (and others)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the implementation, the `si` variants are very simple functions based on the `ui` functions: [`src/si_op.c`](https://gitlab.inria.fr/mpfr/mpfr/-/blob/6785c8c3a1ae1acdf702bc4b13e2a6e7606ffab9/src/si_op.c). So the first reason the `sj` variants are not provided is because the `uj` variants are not provided.

Now, the most basic `ui` variants (like `mpfr_mul_ui` and `mpfr_add_ui`) were added in 1999 and 2000, in the first year of the MPFR development. The first `intmax_t` based functions were added only in 2004 (`mpfr_set_` ones, and `mpfr_get_` ones a few months later). The initial goal was just to be able to do conversions, which is sufficient for most needs: by choosing an adequate precision, one can do an exact conversion to a MPFR number, then the wanted operation similar to the `ui` and `si` variants. Additional variants could be added in the future, but this is not done yet.

Note that the [`TODO`](https://gitlab.inria.fr/mpfr/mpfr/-/blob/6785c8c3a1ae1acdf702bc4b13e2a6e7606ffab9/TODO#L311-314) currently has

```
- mpfr_cmp_uj, mpfr_cmp_sj, mpfr_mul_uj, mpfr_mul_sj. They would be useful
  to test MPFR with _MPFR_EXP_FORMAT=4.
  Note: the code sometimes uses mpfr_cmp_si with __gmpfr_emin or __gmpfr_emax;
  this is incorrect when _MPFR_EXP_FORMAT=4.
```

Such functions would at least be useful internally. But other variants could be added too.

Comment: Extra question: why there are no MPFR functions for `long long` arguments? Or, otherwise, why `mpfr_sub_si` uses `long` instead of `long long`?

Comment: @pmor I think that one reason was that the support for `long long` was more difficult to detect via macros in `mpfr.h`. Moreover, the support for the largest integer type was sufficient to support all the other integer types.

Comment: However, there is no `mpfr_sub_sj`... Hence, it is impossible to subtract 64-bit integer (for example) from `mpfr_t` w/o conversion of such integer to `mpfr_t` using, for example, `mpfr_set_sj`.

Comment: @pmor Yes, the support for `intmax_t` is partial. But internally, the implementation of `mpfr_sub_sj` would probably do a conversion with `mpfr_set_sj` first, or something similar.